# What is 'ng' in cypress

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

```
describe('View: Phone list', function() {
beforeEach(function() {
  cy.visit('/index.html#!/phones')
  cy.ng('model', '$ctrl.query').as('q')
})
```

Pleas tell me someone what this 'ng' mean in this code. I tried to find out in Mocha and Cypress docs, but find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Cypress has an AngularJS helper. I don't use Angular, so not sure what it's for. It's likely something from an old iteration of Cypress (checking `git blame`, latest commits are from 2017), and will be possibly removed in the future.

I wouldn't use it in your specs.

You can check source and specs here:

- [https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/angular.coffee](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/a73f6313c61c8978efbc77488102a44052c1a4bd/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/angular.coffee)
- [https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/commits/develop/packages/driver/test/cypress/integration/commands/angular_spec.coffee](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/d8bdd4a85d899fcd1deb2f9f5ed376790fbcb701/packages/driver/test/cypress/integration/commands/angular_spec.coffee)

Comment: It looks like it can be used to test angularjs model properties